# mu4e inbox update delay

Tags: email, mu4e

incoming mail appears in mu4e inbox long minutes after it is there. 
I can see it in the webmail service online immidiately but in emacs it doesn't show till a few minutes or even half an hour after..

my `mu4e` config:

```
(setq mu4e-get-mail-command "offlineimap")
(setq mu4e-attachment-dir  "~/Downloads")
(setq mu4e-view-show-addresses 't)

#smpt:
(setq mu4e-sent-folder "/Sent"
  mu4e-drafts-folder "/Drafts"
  mu4e-trash-folder "/Trash"
  message-send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
  user-mail-address "MY@EMAIL.COM"
  user-full-name  "Adam Gefen"
  smtpmail-default-smtp-server "smtp.MYMAIL.com"
  smtpmail-smtp-server "MYMAIL.com"
  smtpmail-stream-type 'starttls
  smtpmail-smtp-service 587)

#starting mu4e in its own frame:
(defun mu4e-in-new-frame ()
 "Start mu4e in new frame."
(interactive)
(select-frame (make-frame))
(mu4e))
```

and my .offlineimaprc config is:

```
[general]
accounts = XXXX

[Account XXXX]
localrepository = Local
remoterepository = Remote
autorefresh = 5
quick = 10
postsynchook = mu index --maildir ~/Maildir

[Repository Local]
type = Maildir
localfolders = ~/Maildir

[Repository Remote]
type = IMAP
remotehost = XXXX.COM
remoteuser = MY@EMAIL.COM
remotepass = XXXXXXXX
keepalive = 60
holdconnectionopen = yes
sslcacertfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mu4e` farms out the actual email checking to an external program
such as `offlineimap`.  The variable `mu4e-update-interval`
controls how often `mu4e` will call that program.

Here's the docstring:

> Documentation:
>
> Number of seconds between automatic calls to retrieve mail and
>   update the database. If `nil`, don't update automatically. Note,
>   changes in `mu4e-update-interval` only take effect after restarting
>   `mu4e`.

The following code:

```
(setq mu4e-get-mail-command "offlineimap -o"
      mu4e-update-interval  300)
```

will do the following:

- have `mu4e` run `offlineimap` to fetch mail (the `-o` switch
  is to have `offlineimap` run "once")
- do this every 300 seconds (i.e., every 5 minutes)